# How to Solve 'unable to load class 'org.gradle.initialization.BuildCancellationToken'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When i have been opening my project, after sync my gradle suddenly there is error like this

---

Error:Unable to load class 'org.gradle.initialization.BuildCancellationToken'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

---

Ho to solve that?? please, i need help quickly for my android task

Answer (score 2):

The gradle is corrupt,delete your gradle. On Intellj go to Settings; Build, Execution, Deployment then Gradle and change to a local gradle distribution and download the dependencies.